# hackage showing incorrect dependencies for library package with executable sections

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal, hackage

Hackage shows the union of the dependencies of the Library section as well as all Executable sections, even when I conditionally hide them behind a flag set to `false`.

I've only found this ancient, supposedly-fixed [bug](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/cabal-devel/2010-April/006244.html) which claims that specifying `cabal >= 1.18` solves things, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

What do I need to do to have hackage show only dependencies for the Library section, when the package includes Executable sections?

[Here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashabler-0.1.0.1) is the package that's giving me issues.

Comment: I hope I don't sound a bit stupid, but... what's your question?

Comment: @DanielWagner edited to add "What do I need to do to have hackage show only dependencies for the Library section, when the package includes Executable sections?"

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can control: If there is an executable section, hackage will expect that users will want to build them. This makes sense, and making that configurable will only cause unnecessary complications.

The proper fix in this case is to put the test suite and benchmark programs into proper Cabal sections of that type. See https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#test-suites and https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#benchmarks for their documentation.

Comment: FWIW I don't think it makes sense personally, and it seems like at one point it was declared a bug (unless I'm misreading that old bug report mailing list post). I guess I'll probably just make all the sections `test` sections so I only have to do `--enable-tests` or something.

Comment: @jberryman I think you are misreading the old bug report. That report is about Cabal, not Hackage.